# aiogram python bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

Когда пользователь нажимает на инлайн кнопку, нужно чтобы изменялась переменная message_money, которая позже будет передаваться в @dp.callback_query_handler(text='money_button_qiwi'). Как это можно осуществить?

```
message_money = 0

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет "
                                        , reply_markup=kb.markup)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Каталог")) #Каталог
async def katalog(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "ℹ️Чтобы ознакомиться с каналом, выбери необходимый, нажав на соответствующую кнопку", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains = "pac_") #Инлайн кнопки katalog
async def botShop(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)
    if call.data == "pac_button1":
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Просмотр товара g\n"
                                                  "Цена: 99 *RUB*\n"
                                                  "Срок действия (дней): бессрочно\n\n"
                                                  "Описание тарифа:\n"
                                                  "g", parse_mode= "Markdown", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_nazad_oplata)





@dp.callback_query_handler(text='money_button_qiwi')  # Кнопка оплата qiwi
async def botShop(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, str(message_money), parse_mode= "Markdown", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_oplatil_otmena)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так просто в обработчике инлайн кнопки изменяй значение глобальной переменной.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='money_button_qiwi')  # Кнопка оплата qiwi
async def botShop(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global message_money
    message_money += 1 # или что ты хочешь с ней делать
    await bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, str(message_money), parse_mode= "Markdown", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_oplatil_otmena)
```

Ну а вообще можно чтобы сама инлайн кнопка передавала данные.

```
# Вместо той кнопки вставь эту.
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
    # вместо 123 можно в принципе впихнуть всё что угодно, сообщение пользователя, результат функции и тд
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="текст кнопки", callback_data="money_button_qiwi:123")
)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contain='money_button_qiwi')  # Кнопка оплата qiwi
async def botShop(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    money = call.data.split(':')[1] # здесь будет 123 типа str
    await bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, str(message_money), parse_mode= "Markdown", reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_oplatil_otmena)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант просто нашел, что можно переменную глобальной объявить в `if call.data == "pac_button1":` и все нормально будет.